# Select text with dash in double click PhpStorm

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, phpstorm

With double click in PhpStorm the entire word is selected. But if there is a dash in the text like `full-text` double clicking on it will only select `full`, not the `text`.

Is there any setting to select `full-text` in double click?

Comment: AFAIK it may depend on context (what language it is currently injected there). What's your context?

Comment: For CSS there is a special setting in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys` to have it selected in one go. Otherwise it requires more clicks/different approach.

Comment: It is PHP. Also same issue in Rubymine

Comment: What do you mean by "PHP"? Does PHP (language) allows naming classes/variables with dash in their name? I do not think so. if you are talking about plain text (e.g. words in a string) then I'm not aware of such IDE setting.

Comment: Actually it was a HTML class in PHPStorm.

Comment: IDE version? It seems to work OK in PhpStorm 2017.2.1 EAP build. Does not work like that in 2017.1.4 thuogh.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, double click to select one of the words and then press `ctrl + w`.

Comment: Additional note: the above trick will also allow you to quickly select something like `font-size: 15px;` if you press `Ctrl + W` once more. The more you press this combination the more text will be selected.

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks.